# CSP (Content Security Policy) Ext.js 4.2 issue

Tags: extjs, eval, content-security-policy

I am getting security risk issue when using extjs within my project, specifically `eval()` is flagged and the alternative  to it is using functions, which is again flagged as a risk, due to which I can't make it work.

I am attaching some errors I got before ([using eval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nTTx.png)) and after ([using functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrcwD.png)).

Please suggest alternatives as using `unsafe-eval` is not the solution.

I have also tried the latest version (7.4.0) of EXT-Js but It also contains `new Function ()` and `Function.prototype.constructor.apply()` which is also blocked by CSP.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no alternatives. `new Function()`, `eval()`, `setTimeout('string-func')` and  `setInterval('string-func')` all these are counted as eval-expressions because can create function from a string. Therefore they require `'unsafe-eval'` token in the `script-src` directive.